# Search text box on every column in datatables missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I am using jQuery Datatables to create table with the data pulled from MySQL.

My table looks like this:

```
LOT_LOCATION, Zone Attribute, LOTID, Design_ID, Board_ID1, QA_WORK_REQUEST_NO, QA_CONTACT_NAME, QA_PROCESS_NAME, CURRENT_QTY, Date, Temperature, Humidity, Voltage, Current
SGHAST.0034 1   CVSBCL2.11  J54K    EC100TSI0-017           HAST 110C   40  2022-06-13 13:39:42 28.81   87.9    V1=0.01V, V2=V, V3=V    I1=0.0A, I2=A, I3=A
SGHAST.0034 1   CVSBCL2.11  J54K    EC100TSI0-017           HAST 110C   40  2022-06-13 17:25:34 26.36   92.51   V1=0.01V, V2=V, V3=V    I1=0.0A, I2=A, I3=A
SGHAST.0007 1   CVWHBL2.11  NM112   MP149WSI3-002           HAST 110C   40  2022-06-13 13:39:42 54.97   26.51   V1=0.0V, V2=0.0V, V3=0.0V   I1=0.0A, I2=0.0A, I3=0.0A
```

This is the code for datatables:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  

    var table = $('#elogbooktable').DataTable( {
      "ajax": {url: "testing_getdetaildata.php", dataSrc: ""},
          'scrollCollapse': false,
          'deferRender':    true,
          'scroller':       true,
          'lengthMenu':     [[50, 75, 100, 200, -1], [50, 75, 100, 200, 'ALL']],
          'iDisplayLength': 50,
          'order': [[ 4, "asc" ]],
          'orderCellsTop' : true,

          'columnDefs': [ {
            'targets': 2,
            'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
              if(rowData[2]) {
                  $(td).html("<a href='http://mamweb.sing.micron.com/MAMWeb/bin/MAMWeb.pl?APP=MAMQASI&ACTION=REPORT&REPORTID=Status&MATYPE=78&FORMAT=HTML&CATEGORIES=ALL&ID="+rowData[2]+"' target='_blank'>"+rowData[2]+"</a>");
              }
            }
          }, {
            'targets': 9,
            'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
              if(rowData[9]) {
                  $(td).text(moment(rowData[9]).format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A'));
              }
            }
          }, {
            'targets': 10,
            'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
              if(rowData[10]) {
                  $(td).text(rowData[10] + " C");
              }
            }
          } ,{
            'targets': 11,
            'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
              if(rowData[11]) {
                  $(td).text(rowData[11] + " %RH");
              }
            }
          }],
         rowCallback: function(row, data, index){
            if(new Date(data[9]) < Date.now()){
            $(row).find('td:eq(9)').css('background-color', '#f8d7da');
          }
        },
    });
```

This is the code for the search text box on every columns:

```
table.columns().every( function () {
      $(this.footer()).html("<input type='text' style='width:100%;' placeholder='Search'/>");
    });
```

However, instead of displaying search text box at the row below the header/title, each column shows the repeat of the header/title. I do not know what is the main issue with this since the code is correct and applicable in another webpage.

Any help is appreciated thank you!

EDIT:

here is the json file requested:

```
 {
 "elogbooktable": [
 {
   "Lot_location" : "SGHAST.0034",
   "Zone Attribute" : 1,
   "LOTID" : "CVSBCL2.11",
   "Design_ID" : "J54K",
   "Board_ID1" : "EC100TSI0-017",
   "QA_WORK_REQUEST_NO": "",
   "QA_CONTACT_NAME" : NULL,
   "QA_PROCESS_NAME" : "HAST 110C",
   "CURRENT_QTY" : 40,
   "Date" : 2022-06-13 13:39:42,
   "Temperature" : 28.81,
   "Humidity" : 87.9,
   "Voltage" : "V1=0.01V, V2=V, V3=V",
   "Current" : "I1=0.0A, I2=A, I3=A",
   
 
 },
 
 {
   "Lot_location" : "SGHAST.0034",
   "Zone Attribute" : 1,
   "LOTID" : "CVSBCL2.11",
   "Design_ID" : "J54K",
   "Board_ID1" : "EC100TSI0-017",
   "QA_WORK_REQUEST_NO": "",
   "QA_CONTACT_NAME" : NULL,
   "QA_PROCESS_NAME" : "HAST 110C",
   "CURRENT_QTY" : 40,
   "Date" : 2022-06-13 17:25:34,
   "Temperature" : 26.36,
   "Humidity" : 92.51,
   "Voltage" : "V1=0.01V, V2=V, V3=V",
   "Current" : "I1=0.0A, I2=A, I3=A",
   
 
 },
 
 {
   "Lot_location" : "SGHAST.0007",
   "Zone Attribute" : 1,
   "LOTID" : "CVWHBL2.11",
   "Design_ID" : "NM112",
   "Board_ID1" : "MP149WSI3-002",
   "QA_WORK_REQUEST_NO": "",
   "QA_CONTACT_NAME" : NULL,
   "QA_PROCESS_NAME" : "HAST 110C",
   "CURRENT_QTY" : 40,
   "Date" : 2022-06-13 13:39:42,
   "Temperature" : 54.97,
   "Humidity" : 26.51,
   "Voltage" : "V1=0.0V, V2=0.0V, V3=0.0V",
   "Current" : "I1=0.0A, I2=0.0A, I3=0.0A",
   
 
 }

 ]
 }
```

Comment: One common issue in datatables is the use of different version and applying that API syntax to another version. Generally, find the datatable version and the API syntax version you are using. That should fix it. I've faced it many times.

Comment: i am very new to this so i am not quite sure what u meant

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Remove every single piece of code which is not relevant to the problem. (For example, you can remove every column which is not needed to show the problem. You can remove every configuration option which is not needed to show the problem. And so on...). Simplify your code for us.

Comment: Instead of providing your source data in tabular format, can you provide that data as JSON text, instead? JSON is what the DataTable receives from `testing_getdetaildata.php`. Show us what the DataTable receives.

Comment: @andrewJames I have added the json text. and regarding the impt code required i alr highlighted in the qn the one starting with the 'table.columns()'. thank you!

Comment: I appreciate the updates, thank you. But the code in the question is not usable. I spent time trying to  re-work it into a usable state, but I failed. Just a few problems (not all of them): (1) The JSON is not valid. (2) The JSON contains an object called `elogbooktable` - but all the rest of the code assumes the JSON is only an array. So the JSON is incompatible with the DataTable definition. (3) The code for the search boxes - where is that supposed to be placed? it refers to `table` - but `table` does not exist unless the function waits for initialization to finish.

Comment: (4) Where do you create "the row below the header/title"? That is not shown anywhere in the question. (5) How are most of the 12(?) columns supposed to be populated? The `columnDefs` option only refers to 4 of the 12 columns - what about the other 8? (6) It still seems as if almost all of the code is irrelevant to the problem you are seeing. Why don't you remove all of that irrelevant code? (7) It looks as if there are extra libraries needed by the code in the question - such as `moment` and maybe others (`bootstrap`, perhaps?). Are these relevant?

Comment: @andrewJames apologies! idk how to turn the datatables data to a JSON text. (3) & (4) the search box shld be directly below the title. So i what i want is sth like this : https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html, roughly following this code with the table.column() code but did not work. (5) the other columns are automatically filled because they r from mySQL data table. (7) I tried removing them

Comment: @andrewJames the code i provided the table.column() can be used in other webpage that has similar tables using similar code for datatables. Only when i changed the datatable content that the search boxes suddenly missing.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and updates again. Unfortunately, I am not able to build a working demo (a MRE) using the code and data in the question. Without that, I cannot recreate the problem you are facing. When I tried to create a MRE using your code, I had to make a lot of assumptions, fix the issues I mentioned earlier, and provide some missing code. The end result was code which works correctly for me. It was basically your code, converted into the [example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) you mentioned in your last comment.

Comment: @andrewJames thank you but i managed to solve it apparently it was linked to another feature of showing/hiding extra columns, so i just needed to delete the part and everything works well.

Comment: Good news! Why don't you write that as an answer, where you can show the solution.

Comment: glad, you got it working. And @andrewJames was very helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try an alternative example and see if that works?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#elogbooktable tfoot th').each(function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
    });
});
```

Comment: This still does not work